# How to detect user idle time since last touch and return the app to home page using phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, touches

I would like to check for the user idle time since last touch and return the app to the home page after some period of time. I want this to be done using phonegap.

I googled and did find few solutions but I want to detect the idle time and return the app to the home page.

Thanks.

Comment: you want to detect the idle time in the app or when the idle time when the user has navigated out of the app?

Comment: I want to check the idle time in the app and return to home page after some period of time has elapsed.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you *could bind a start touch event and end touch event then using a timer to execute a function

```
$('body').bind('touchstart',function() {
    clearInterval(myTimer);
});

$('body').bind('touchend', function() {
     myTimer = setInterval(function() { 
                          /* return user to homepage */
                        },30000);
});
```

Touch events are a little buggy in mobile devices. But you set an Interval timer to run after a set amount of time after the last touch is detected. Remembering to clear it on the next touchstart event. Its a bit messy but should work (I havent tested it btw)

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I will try it and let you know

Comment: I got this working by setTimeout('Redirect()', 10000); where Redirect fn is function Redirect()
            {
                window.location.href="mylink.html";
            }

Comment: Glad you got it working, please mark as answered to help others !

Comment: Yeah I will do it. As am a newbie am not able to answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by setTimeout('Redirect()', 10000); where Redirect fn is function Redirect() { window.location.href="mylink.html"; }